# What does RNG mean? comments extension

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

This question is being created at Rapitor's behest to take the discussion taking place in the comments of [What does RNG mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212289/what-does-rng-mean) elsewhere.

Comment: Basically to summarize what went down (as I see it): The question originally was something along the lines of "what does RNG mean" which can easily be found by a simple google search. You edited the question (after many complaints and downvotes) to add this information, but there was still something you are looking for in the answer. Correct? unfortunately many of our questions (and I'm even sure a handful of mine) can be answered with a simple google search. Why yours was singled out this heavily I am not certain.

Comment: I suspect that this question was downvoted that heavily because of how OP's responses in the comments and edits were perceived.

Comment: (1) I don't think the explanation that RNG stands for "random number generator" fully explains its meaning, as it seems most definitions start and stop at. (2) I edited the question to add evidence of research. (3) There is still something I am looking for in an answer.

Comment: If there is something you are still looking for in an answer, the close reason indicates that people reading your question don't know what it is. You should make it explicit in your question *what* it is that you want to know.

Comment: It's also possible the question was downvoted because this question, along with a number of questions by OP, seem to be designed to farm for reputation.

Answer (score 7):

The thing about your question is that there isn't a *question* there anymore.  It was originally downvoted, but left open, due to the question being trivially easy to answer.  That's to be expected for simple questions.  Once you attempted to provide some research to counteract the downvotes, you *answered your own question*.

> A Google search (which seems to automatically search for "random number generator" as well) of the term.

There you go.  You know what it is.  Your research has led you to the answer.  What point is there to asking about it on Arqade now?  That's why it's closed as Unclear.  It's the equivalent of, "Uh.  You know what it means.  Why are you asking?"

Doing some simple research before asking this would have obviated the need for this question, and the meta questions that have spawned from it.  The original question could have been kept, but shouldn't be expected to get a good reception.  Your question *after* the fact isn't a question anymore.

Comment: Yes, there is a question. (2) I did not answer my own question; I did not post an answer to my own question. (3) Merriam-Webster says "rng" means "range", but I think we can agree that that is not appropriate here. So, why should I assume that Google's automatic inclusion is appropriate? (4) The point of asking about it on Arqade is so that Arqade may answer it for all. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212289/what-does-rng-mean#comment287329_212289 (5) That is not the same thing as unclear. (6) Yes, research that could have been done on Arqade, (cont'd)

Comment: but wouldn't having the question/answer here on arqade benefit everyone? It does increase our traffic (which is a good thing). Just because the answer is already relatively easily obtained doesn't mean it doesn't belong on Arqade. Seeing as our goal (as I see it) is to be the go-to source for all gaming questions... "obvious" questions should be just as allowed as other questions (just be careful of dupes)

Comment: with such a question if it had existed before, definitively, and not in a question that incidentally explains its meaning.

Comment: @NiteCyper 1) If there is a question, *what is it*?  Nobody knows what it is besides yourself.  2) How did you NOT answer it?  Your attempt at research says you have an understanding of what it means.  You need to clarify exactly what it is you're looking for.  3) Is a decent point, but is obviated by the research you did.  One source gives what you think is a wrong definition, but the rest of your research points overwhelmingly to the solution.  4) Asking a question on Arqade solely so that it exists here...will meet a very chilly reception.  It speaks to ulterior motivation.

Comment: 5) It most certainly is.  *We don't know what you're asking*.  6) We don't *require* research, but don't expect a good response if you don't.  That's exactly how this is playing out.

Comment: @Rapitor That's...a bit of a wonky area.  There's something to be said for driving traffic here, but there's also something to be said about trying to keep the experts; the two have to be in balance, so while there's an argument to be made for driving traffic, if that's the sole reason for asking a question, it's not going to be very well received; letting people ask questions organically results in much better content, overall.  Good faith and all that.

Comment: @Rapitor Obvious questions *are* allowed. The question was downvoted, not closed, for being obvious. It was only closed when the question was edited to the point where it is unclear what OP still wants out of an answer, hence the close reason.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think the issue then is why are obvious ones being downvoted so hard.

Comment: @Rapitor That's easy; the community wants *interesting* questions.  Easily googled terms, aren't.

Comment: If a question can be answered by Google Searching the title verbatim, it's clear that there was no research *effort*. That's the canonical downvote reason, so downvotes on such questions should be expected.

Comment: (1) What does RNG mean (in the context of video-games)? (2) How I did not answer it is by not posting an answer to my own question. Neither did I claim that my finds were the answer, but merely the evidence of my research. My attempt at research does not necessarily say that I have an understanding of what it means, but neither do I see the point of this assertion. (3) And probably the majority of humanity once thought Earth is flat. My goal is to ask and have it answered on Arqade, not just find an answer for myself. (4) Sorry that I do things towards Arqade's supposed goal.

Comment: @NiteCyper You seem to be confused about the goal of any stack exchange site. The goal is to provide helpful information. Your question does not further this goal, because the information it asks for is extremely easily accessible.

Comment: @NiteCyper And you can see how that's working out for you.  Asking a question solely so that it exists here is a rather bad reason to ask.  If you absolutely, *positively* want to keep this question, roll it back to the original question.  You will garner more downvotes, but I believe that's the only way we can actually accept it.  If you want it to be both upvoted *and* acceptable, I believe you're going to be left disappointed.  In this case, the best you can hope for is acceptable.

Comment: @NiteCyper You ask what "RNG" means. Then your question has a bunch of information indicating that "RNG" means "Random Number Generator." There, that's it; that's your answer. You have clearly demonstrated that a modicum of research makes the question *unnecessary*. So, as Frank says, you can't have it both ways. You can either ask a question without research, or a question that doesn't need answering.

Comment: @Frank I will trust your assertion that rolling it back returns it to acceptability.

Comment: I will also vote to reopen if it is rolled back. That will probably be close to enough.

Answer (score -4):

"You can't [show research without answering the question], because it is a ridiculously trivial question. That's why it was down voted, but left open, until you stopped it being a question when it was closed." - [TZHX](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212289/what-does-rng-mean?noredirect=1#comment287407_212289)

I could say the same (that it is a ridiculously trivial question) about [What is kiting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18903/what-is-kiting), yet it is one of the highest voted terminology questions, not to mention its apparent lack of research effort.

Comment: What's your point? That that other question should be downvoted? If you think so, go downvote it.

Comment: I guess my point is that a complaint of lack of research is moot if the downvoter believes that the question cannot add detail without potentially answering itself. Secondly, they malign my question when there is evidence of a similar question that seems to serve its purpose fine in contrast, so it seems the maligning is personal.

Comment: When similar questions get different receptions, as in this case, it's almost always because standards have changed over the years (that question is almost 4 years old) and because there are different people looking at them. It's **not** personal.

Comment: And my action to that question would have been exactly the same. What's your point? I down vote about ten times as much as I upvote because I have an aversion to stupid. Lack of research is my reason in most cases. Attitude of poster rarely comes in to it, but I think for some people this could be a factor.

Comment: Actually , kiting is a primarily gaming term that isn't immediately explained by expanding the acronym. So it's a much better question. I won't dv it.

Comment: The kiting question was asked four years ago, when searching for it on Google didn't give an obvious answer. It does give a somewhat obvious answer now (once you get past the information about actual kites), but that's still much less obvious than the big infobox at the top of the page when you search "what does rng stand for?"

Comment: I actually used Google's time feature to see what google looked like at the time. The top results are about check-kiting which is completely different and you have to dig well into the first page to find a wowwiki link.